# Installing clang 3.4 and LLVM 3.4 on ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, clang, llvm

I want to install clang-3.4 , opt-3.4 and llc-3.4 on my ubuntu 16.04.
I want specific version 3.4 only.

opt-3.4: It is LLVM optimizer.

llc-3.4: It is LLVM static compiler.

Running the installation command gives me error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang-3.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package clang-3.4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  clang-5.0:i386 clang-3.9:i386 clang-3.8:i386 clang:i386 clang-5.0 clang-3.9 clang-3.8 clang clang-4.0:i386 clang-4.0 clang-3.7:i386
  clang-3.6:i386 clang-3.5:i386 clang-3.7 clang-3.6 clang-3.5

E: Package 'clang-3.4' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install the 3.4 version of packages?

EDIT:

Answers on how to port the project to a recent version of clang is also welcome.

Comment: Why do you need such an ancient, outdated, bug-ridden version? You'd probably be better served asking how to port whatever you're doing to a more reasonable version of Clang.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. What in particular goes wrong if you try to compile your old code with a new compiler?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck with this question on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What happens if you compile your project with a current Clang? You need to provide a lot more information if you want some help.

Comment: I've ported code from 3.4-vingate to modern LLVM. It was a bit of a slog but not particularly difficult. A few days of looking at error messages, finding out how LLVM had changed and updating the source. Most of the LLVM changes were trivial, e.g. calls to `new Foo(…)` replaced with `Foo::Create(…)`. Good luck.